# android how to show application icon in notification bar after certain time period

Tags: android

im using this tutorial   http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-Android--Day-16%E2%80%93Notifications   for show applictaion in notifdication bar but is show continusly my icon in notifcation bar i want to is show or alert after certain time period.what do ido??

```
 public class DaySixteenActivity extends BaseActivity {
private TextView lblTextViewOne;
private EditText editText1;
public static int notificationId = 0;

public static String MyStaticString;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  
    Log.i("DaySixteenActivity", "onCreate Start");

    lblTextViewOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblTextViewOne);
    lblTextViewOne.setText(R.string.test_one);

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText1.setText(R.string.test_one);



    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lblTextViewOne.setText(editText1.getText());

            String notificationService = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager notificationManager = 
(NotificationManager) getSystemService(notificationService);            

            Notification notification = new 
 Notification(R.drawable.cherry_icon, 

 "Hello Notification!", System.currentTimeMillis());


            Intent notificationIntent = new  
Intent(getApplicationContext(), DaySixteenActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = 
PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                                            notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), 
 "Notification Title", 
                                            "CherryApplication", contentIntent);




            notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
        }
    });     

    Log.i("DaySixTeenActivity", "onCreate End");
}

}


          public class MyApplication extends Application {
private String myApplicationString;

public String getMyApplicationString() {
    return myApplicationString;
}

public void setMyApplicationString(String myApplicationString) {
    this.myApplicationString = myApplicationString;
}       
 }



               public class PassableObject implements Parcelable {
private String myStringValue;

public PassableObject() {}

public PassableObject(Parcel inParcel) {
    myStringValue = inParcel.readString();
}

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}




                  public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.item1:
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                DaySixteenActivity.class));
        //End the current activity
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
    }


public void writeToParcel(Parcel outParcel, int flags) {
    outParcel.writeString(myStringValue);
}

public String getMyStringValue() {
    return myStringValue;
}

public void setMyStringValue(String myStringValue) {
    this.myStringValue = myStringValue;
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<PassableObject> CREATOR 
= new Parcelable.Creator<PassableObject>() {
    public PassableObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new PassableObject(in);
    }

    public PassableObject[] newArray(int size) {
        return new PassableObject[size];
    }
};
  }
```

Comment: this code work fine show icon innotification bar,.but i want to display notification every 15 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put uppercase notification service

```
 notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notifyDetails=new Notification(
                                                R.drawable.icon,contentTitle,System.currentTimeMillis());

        notificationManager .notify(MY_SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
```

Try this its works for me..

Comment: no i want to use timer so notification bar appear every 15 minutes

Answer (score 1):

you can use `AlarmManager` for that
check these link for more info

[Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example/8801990#8801990)

and
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: @lovelyguy you can use BroadcastReceiver for that... here is the example  http://smartandroidians.blogspot.com/2010/04/alarmmanager-and-notification-in.html

Comment: i want to start remainder of notification every 15 minutes

Comment: in the setRepeatingAlarm method put 15*60*1000* in place of 5*1000